# Convert Person/User Group to String

Tags: client-object-model, user, string

I am retrieving a list that contains Persons and would like to convert them to String, and also be able to count how many users are per list. The Person is retrieved as an Object. How can I solve this issue?

```
var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
itemValue = oListItem.get_item('Title');
alert(itemValue); //prints correctly
peopleValue = oListItem.get_item('People').get_lookupId();
alert("My name is" + peopleValue); //prints [object, object]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using get_lookupValue() should work.

If you're reading out a multi user it's slightly different too.

```
//Get user field value
var peopleVal = item.get_item('People').get_lookupValue();


//Get multi user field value
var peopleVals = item.get_item('People');
for(var i = 0; i < peopleVals.length;i++) {
     var userName = peopleVals[i].get_lookupValue();   
}
```